# Custom time series resampling in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have a df with OHLC data in a 1m frequency:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
DateTime                                               
2005-09-06 18:00:00  1230.25  1231.50  1230.25  1230.25
2005-09-06 18:01:00  1230.50  1231.75  1229.25  1230.50
.
.
2005-09-07 15:59:00  1234.50  1235.50  1234.25  1234.50
2005-09-07 16:00:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.25  1234.25
```

I need to do a "custom" resample that fits futures hours data where:

- Every day starts at 18:00:00 of the previous day (Monday starts on Sunday 18:00:00)
- Every day ends at 16:00:00 of the current day
- The timestamp should be as of the the time of the close, not the open.

After doing the resample, the output should be:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
DateTime                                               
2005-09-07 16:00:00  1230.25  1235.50  1229.25  1234.25
```

Where:

- Open = first (column Open) at 2005-09-06 18:00:00
- High = max (column High) from  2005-09-06 18:00:00 to 2005-09-07 16:00:00
- Low = min (column Low) from  2005-09-06 18:00:00 to 2005-09-07 16:00:00
- Close = last (column Close) at 2005-09-07 16:00:00

I have tried:

- Changing the parameters rule, and base, but it didn't work.
- Playing with reindex with no success.

I used the following 'how':

```
conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}
```

Comment: Can we take every day as ending at 18:00 of the current day, otherwise, what should be done about DateTimes between 16:00 and 18:00?

Comment: @unutbu That's a good question. You can discard that data between 16:01 and 17:59. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')
# Make sure the index is a DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

# discard rows whose time falls between 16:00 and 18:00
df = df.between_time('18:00', '16:00', include_start=True, include_end=True)

proxy = df.index + pd.DateOffset(hours=6)
result = df.groupby(proxy.date).agg(
    {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
result = result.reindex(columns=['Open','High','Low','Close'])
print(result)
```

yields

```
               Open    High      Low    Close
2005-09-07  1230.25  1235.5  1229.25  1234.25
```

---

The code above creates a proxy date which is calculated by adding 6 hours to each datetime in the index. This proxy date is then used as the `groupby` value.

```
In [112]: proxy = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index) + pd.DateOffset(hours=6)
```

To see how the proxy values correspond to the index:

```
In [116]: pd.Series(proxy.date, index=df.index)
Out[116]: 
DateTime
2005-09-06 18:00:00    2005-09-07
2005-09-06 18:01:00    2005-09-07
2005-09-07 15:59:00    2005-09-07
2005-09-07 16:00:00    2005-09-07
dtype: object
```

Comment: So I ran it in my real df of 3mill rows and it takes about 3 min. It works ok, except in one day that for some reason it doesn't give the right print. I have to check the detail. Do you think you can show me how you would do it if you could take every day as ending at 18:00 of current day?

Comment: Essentially the same code should work; just remove the line the begins `df = df.between_time(...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. This does exactly what I need. It runs in 1min35sec. I would try to make it run faster. I appreciate if you have any suggestions.