# Pandas: How to get the most immediately preceding row that fulfills a condition? Something like a variable-length shift

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table, indexed by `date`, that has values of `price` that I want to use when creating a new column, `previous_close`.

```
date                | price
2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2
2019-01-01 04:00:00 | 3
2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 4
2019-01-01 04:00:00 | 5
```

I want to generate a column `previous_close` that returns the value of `price` in a row of the previous day's last price, so the output will be as follows:

```
date                | price | previous_close
2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2     | NaN
2019-01-01 04:00:00 | 3     | NaN
2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 4     | 3
2019-01-02 04:00:00 | 5     | 3
```

So far the only way I've figured how is to use `df.apply`, which iterates row-wise and for every row filters the index for the latest preceding day's last row. However, even though the DataFrame is date-indexed this takes a lot of time; for a table with a hundred thousand rows it takes several minutes to populate.

I was wondering if there was any way to create the new series in a vectorized form; something like df.shift(num_periods) but with the num_periods adjusted according to the row's `date` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest as in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416281/pandas-join-resampled-df-with-original-df-by-data-range) for the reindexing part:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("2019-01-01 22:00:00", periods=10, freq="H"),
                   "price": np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)})
df = df.set_index("date")

df = pd.concat([df.price, 
           df.resample("d").last().shift().rename(columns={"price":"close"}).reindex(df.index, method='ffill')], 
           axis = 1)
```

And you get the result:

```
                    price  close
date                             
2019-01-01 22:00:00     67    NaN
2019-01-01 23:00:00     93    NaN
2019-01-02 00:00:00     99   93.0
2019-01-02 01:00:00     18   93.0
2019-01-02 02:00:00     84   93.0
2019-01-02 03:00:00     58   93.0
2019-01-02 04:00:00     87   93.0
2019-01-02 05:00:00     98   93.0
2019-01-02 06:00:00     97   93.0
2019-01-02 07:00:00     48   93.0
```

EDIT:
If your business day ends at 2 and you want the close for this hour, I suggest using `DateOffset` (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169851/custom-time-series-resampling-in-pandas)) on the date and doing the same method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("2019-01-01 22:00:00", periods=10, freq="H"),
                   "price": np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)})
df["proxy"] = df.date + pd.DateOffset(hours=-3)
df = df.set_index("proxy")
df = pd.concat([df[["price", "date"]], 
          (df.price.resample("d").last().shift()
                   .rename({"price":"close"})
                   .reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))],
          axis = 1).reset_index(drop=True).set_index("date")
```

You get the result:

```
                     price  price
date                             
2019-01-01 22:00:00     67    NaN
2019-01-01 23:00:00     93    NaN
2019-01-02 00:00:00     99    NaN
2019-01-02 01:00:00     18    NaN
2019-01-02 02:00:00     84    NaN
2019-01-02 03:00:00     58   84.0
2019-01-02 04:00:00     87   84.0
2019-01-02 05:00:00     98   84.0
2019-01-02 06:00:00     97   84.0
2019-01-02 07:00:00     48   84.0
```

Comment: Thanks Raphaele! What if I had a day range that crosses the midnight mark, so resample("d").last() does not return the last value of the "day"? For example, getting the day-close price of a market which has a trading day of 10pm-2am. Is translation the only way to go?

Comment: @Zoos I edited the answer to include this possibility using `DateOffset`.